# How do I set a world background texture in Blender 2.49 using Python?

Tags: python, 3d, textures, blender, bpython

I'm trying to set a background World Texture in Blender 2.49.

I've made a texture:

```
import Blender 
from Blender import * 
import bpy 

world = World.GetCurrent() 
worldTex = Texture.New('worldTex') 
worldTex.setType('Image') 
worldIm = Image.Load('//blender_scene/tex/bg 001.jpg') 
worldIm.source = Image.Sources.SEQUENCE 
worldTex.setImage(worldIm)
```

When I try to apply to the world, that will throw and error, because, by default world.textures contains a tuple of None.
so this wouldn't work:

```
world.textures[0].tex = worldTex
```

I've made a material so I can get an MTex instance:

```
worldMat = Material.New('WorldMat')
worldMat.setTexture(worldTex)
```

If I try to set the first texture:

```
world.textures[0] = worldMat.textures[0]
```

That will throw an error, since I can't assign a value to an already initialized tuple.

If I try to replace it:

```
world.textures = worldMat.textures
```

I get yet another error:

```
TypeError: expected tuple or list containing world MTex objects and NONE
```

'world **MTex**' objects got me thinking a bit. Is there another kind of MTex object ? a world MTex ? Where is it defined, how can I create an instance ?

Or as the title states...how do I set a texture to a world ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender 2.5x has a much better Python API. I really recommend watching this [video from PyCon](http://www.blendernation.com/2011/03/17/blender-at-pycon-2011/) talk by Christopher Webber about it.

Setting texture in 2.5x API :

```
import bpy
# create new clouds texture
bpy.ops.texture.new()
t = bpy.data.textures[-1]
# set World texture
w = bpy.data.world['World']
slot = w.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = t
slot.use_map_horizon = True
```

Comment: very interesting talk, thank you for the resource. Indeed Blender 2.5 would be nicer, but Blender 2.49 was a requirement at the time, which is why specifically mentioned 2.49. As a dirty workaround, I added a material slot into the default blender template so I could move on, but I am still interested in what's going on there and what the real solution is.

Comment: I've started Blender from 2.5x, so I can't help you here. Sorry.